# How to display all options in one line using antd Select component?

Tags: reactjs, components, antd

```
<Select
  className="select-color"
  dropdownStyle={{ minWidth: "200px" }}
  onChange={this.handleChange}>
  <Option value="blue" className="blue-color">
    <div style={{backgroundColor: "pink", color:"#fff", width:20, height:20, borderRadius: 5}} />
  </Option>
  <Option value="green">green</Option>
  <Option value="aqua">aqua</Option>
</Select>
```

I want all options in one line in fixed width.

Comment: Can you explain more or provide a sample image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.select-color option{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    float:left;
}
```